# Bitrix комментарии

Tags: битрикс, комментарии

Подскажите на сайте в разделе новости использую компонент bitrix:catalog.comments скопировал в отдельную директорию. Поместил блок кода вызывающий компонент в шаблон news.detail. Итогом стала ошибка:
**В настройках компонента не выбран ни один тип комментариев**

Comment: А компонент вы настроили?

Answer (score 0):

зайдите в настройки компонента

Там три типа комментариев. Собственные на сайте, комменты вк и фб. Вам надо выбрать хотя бы один тип. Если в настройках компонента не видите галочки рядом с Комментарии на сайте, посмотрите установленные модули и есть ли там Блоги.